# '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Next''

Tags: ios

```
- (IBAction)btnsv:(id)sender
{


    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];



    search=NO;

    obj= [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Next" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [obj setValue:self.nm.text forKey:@"name"];
    [obj setValue:self.db.text forKey:@"dob"];
    [obj setValue:self.ct.text forKey:@"city"];
    [obj setValue:self.st.text forKey:@"state"];
    [obj setValue:self.pn.text forKey:@"phone"];
    [obj setValue:self.pw.text forKey:@"pwd"];



    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];

    self.nm.text=@"";
    self.db.text=@"";
    self.ct.text=@"";
    self.st.text=@"";
    self.pn.text=@"";
    self.pw.text=@"";


    NSFetchRequest *req=[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];

    NSEntityDescription *entiyy=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Next" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [req setEntity:entiyy];
    NSError *errorjj;
    [context save:&errorjj];

    nxt=[context executeFetchRequest:req error:&errorjj];

    NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>>");



}
```

Comment: Your question has been down voted because a code dump and a title do not really count as a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
```

This line is giving you `nil` rather than a managed object context. The error message is saying that you can't use `nil` as the `managedObjectContext` parameter for the `entityForName` method.

Your problem is elsewhere in your code - how is `[self managedObjectContext]` set up?